# How to get payload size from custom handler in WSO2 APIM

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I am trying to get payload size from both request and response for every kind of content type with custom handler in WSO2 APIM1.10.0

By reference [this code](https://github.com/wso2/carbon-apimgt/blob/carbon-apimgt-v1.9.1/components/apimgt/org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.usage/org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.usage.publisher/src/main/java/org/wso2/carbon/apimgt/usage/publisher/APIMgtResponseHandler.java), I can get the payload size with 2 ways:

1. Get header content length (at line 127)
2. Build message and get the body length (at line 132)

But I think both of these two way might have some problem.

1. User might give incorrect content length when invoking the API.
2. The API content type might be unpredictable.

So, how can I get payload size from both request and response?

Answer (score 2):

You can do this by using a script mediator. 
The length of the payload of the message can be received by  calling `mc.getPayloadXML()` inside script mediator in both in-sequence and out-sequence. 
Please refer this [blog](http://sajithr.blogspot.com/2014/08/determining-size-of-soap-message-inside.html) for more information and the [documentation](https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM1100/Adding+Mediation+Extensions) on usage of mediation extentions in API Manager.

Comment: Thanks for the reply

Comment: I could get the body length from the log file. But is there a way to get the body length from my java custom handler ?

Comment: You can access the payload in your handler by building the message inside the **hanldeResponse** and **handleRequest** methods before reading the message. But as per my knowledge you cannot get the payload size from the synapse.MessageContext as there is no such method implemented there.

Comment: Please refer the answer provided  [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31697415/how-to-access-response-payload-content-from-custom-handler-in-wso2-apim-1-9) for accessing the payload in custom handlers.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, the reference you provided seem like to build message by using RelayUtils object. But the RelayUtils object looks only support XML format, is there a way to support any custom hypermedia type ?

Comment: Let's not deviate from our question since it is a different question and it has already addressed in that reference. I hope you got the answer for the question that you asked.